# No route matches [GET] on a resource declared in the routes file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

When I click a link generated by the following code in a view:

```
<%= link_to "Colleague", collaborators_path(member2_id: user.id,), :method => :post %>
```

I get the following error message:

```
No route matches [GET] "/collaborators"
```

However, I have the following line in my routes file:

```
resources :collaborators, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

And I have the following definition written out in the collaborators_controller:

```
  @collaboration = current_user.collaborations.build(:member2_id => params[:member2_id])
      if @collaboration.save
        flash[:notice] = "Added collaborator."
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        flash[:error] = "Unable to add collaborator."
        redirect_to root_url
      end
```

So shouldn't the path for creating a collaboration be found by the router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using `only: [:create, :destroy]`. You'd need to include `:index` in that  array for there to be a `GET /collaborators` route. See the [Rails guide on Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)

And in order to use links with `:method => :post`, you'll need to be using Rails 3's [unobtrusive Javascript](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) feature.

Comment: I've added support for the index action.  Even still, I want that link to call the create action of Collaborators, not the index action.  How should the link should be formatted?

Comment: Are you using Rails 3's [unobtrusive Javascript](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/)? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782310/rails3-link-to-method-post-and-no-route-matches-dropup) for a related issue

Comment: I added unobtrusive Javascript (it involved me adding the following lines to a Javascript file: //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `:method => :post` is being ignored because you are using a link. POST method is commonly used when submiting forms. Actually, POST method is used to send data from the browser to the server in order to add new records to a database. See the [Wikipedia article on HTTP methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) for more info, and also [Rails Guides on Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

If what you are trying to do is adding someone as a Colleague (just like Twitter's "follow" action, or Facebook's "Like") then you need to create an small form with the user's id in a hidden field.

**TL;DR**: use a form to create a relation, for a link won't work :)